# Can get response from server PokeApi AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, json, url, pokeapi

Good morning,

I am currently working on a project in android studio in Java on the PokeApi Api. Unfortunately, I can't get a response from the server even though the link is accessible from a browser. If you have an idea, I'm interested.
Thanks.

My class :

```
public class PokemonDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int idPokemon;
    private String imagePokemon;

    private String urlPokemonDetails1 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/";
    private String urlPokemonDetails2 = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon_detail);

        idPokemon = getIntent().getIntExtra("POKEMON_SELECTION_ID", -1);
        imagePokemon = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_POKEMON");

        urlPokemonDetails1 += idPokemon + "/";
        urlPokemonDetails2 += idPokemon + "/";

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        TextView nomPokemon = findViewById(R.id.nom_pokmeon);

        //on associe la postion du pokemon au textView
        TextView positionPokemon = findViewById(R.id.posture_pokemon);

        // on associe la taille du pokemon au textView
        TextView taillePokemon = findViewById(R.id.taille_pokemon);

        // on associe l'habitat du pokemon au textView
        TextView habitatPokemon = findViewById(R.id.habitat_pokemon);

        // on associe les stats du pokemon aux textView
        TextView hpPokemon = findViewById(R.id.hp);
        TextView attaquePokemon = findViewById(R.id.attaque);
        TextView defensePokemon = findViewById(R.id.defense);
        TextView attaqueSpePokemon = findViewById(R.id.attaque_speciale);
        TextView defenseSpePokemon = findViewById(R.id.defense_speciale);
        TextView vitessePokemon = findViewById(R.id.vitesse);

        // on associe l'image du pokemon à l'imageView
        Picasso.get().load(imagePokemon).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_pokemon));


        final String[] response = {""};

        try {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlPokemonDetails1,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String rep) {
                            response[0] += rep;

                            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                            try {
                                jsonObj = new JSONObject(response[0]);

                                //get the name of the pokemon
                                String namePokemon = jsonObj.getString("name");

                                // get the living area of the pokemon
                                JSONObject habitat = jsonObj.getJSONObject("habitat");
                                String habitatPok = habitat.getString("name");

                                // get the shape of the pokemon
                                JSONObject shape = jsonObj.getJSONObject("shape");
                                String shapePokemon = shape.getString("name");

                                nomPokemon.setText(namePokemon);
                                habitatPokemon.setText(habitatPok);
                                positionPokemon.setText(shapePokemon);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("Erreur de téléchargement : ", error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
            queue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlPokemonDetails2,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String rep) {
                            response[1] += rep;

                            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                            try {
                                jsonObj = new JSONObject(response[1]);

                                // get the height of the pokemon
                                int heightPokemon = jsonObj.getInt("height");

                                // get the stats of the pokemon
                                JSONArray stats = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stats");
                                JSONObject stat = stats.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONObject stat1 = stats.getJSONObject(1);
                                JSONObject stat2 = stats.getJSONObject(2);
                                JSONObject stat3 = stats.getJSONObject(3);
                                JSONObject stat4 = stats.getJSONObject(4);
                                JSONObject stat5 = stats.getJSONObject(5);
                                int hp = stat.getInt("base_stat");
                                int attack = stat1.getInt("base_stat");
                                int defense = stat2.getInt("base_stat");
                                int specialAttack = stat3.getInt("base_stat");
                                int specialDefense = stat4.getInt("base_stat");
                                int speed = stat5.getInt("base_stat");

                                taillePokemon.setText(heightPokemon);
                                hpPokemon.setText(hp);
                                attaquePokemon.setText(attack);
                                defensePokemon.setText(defense);
                                attaqueSpePokemon.setText(specialAttack);
                                defenseSpePokemon.setText(specialDefense);
                                vitessePokemon.setText(speed);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("Erreur de téléchargement : ", error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
            queue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: error description]

Do you think it may be caused by the response too long returned by the server maybe ?

I tried to implement library Volley to get the "response" by the server but that didn't solved the problem and to make one class for this.

Update : Why my String tab 'result' is empty (and above all why the server doesn't return me anything)..
[image: error tab result empty...]

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` array has only one element (at index 0):

```java
final String[] response = {""};
```

this makes the string array to conceptually look like this: `[""]`. This way there is no problem in accessing the first element of the array like this: `response[0]`.

Trying to access the second element in the array like this: `response[1]` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since there is no element at index 1 for an array of size 1 (with an element only at the index 0).

You probably want to initialize your array so it looks like this: `["", ""]` this way:

```java
final String[] response = {"", ""};
```

You also shouldn't worry about the problem being

> caused by the response too long returned by the server

Comment: Hi, I have tested your proposition but unfortunately I think it may be caused by the empty answer of the server but I don't know why. Look at my screen below in debug mode for the String tab result (I have had it on my post because I can't put it here..

Comment: Then in what line was the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happening? Now the question tells there is an exception while also saying that the array has two empty string elements and the exception does not seem to have a place to occur. To me now it seems like you've applied my answer which helped you to resolve the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` issue but now you have a totally different problem with the API which should be resolved in a different question or just by yourself.

Comment: Hi, yup thanks. I've solved the problem ! In fact I couldn't use the asynchronous calls with Volley at the same time. So I put second call at the end of the first.